# How to import photos/videos from USB stick to Windows Live Photo Gallery

Tags: windows-7, import, windows-photo-gallery, windows-live-photo

When I pop in my camera, Windows Live Photo Gallery allows me to import the photos into a folder I predefined (on network storage) earlier.  I have it setup to create a folder for each date that the photo was taken.

I'd like to do the same thing when I pop in a USB stick full of pictures.  However, I don't see any options to do that.  There is an option to "Include Folder", but then the photos won't be copied to my predefined directory.

How to import photos/videos from USB stick?  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\AutoPlay

For the entry for Pictures, select "Import pictures and videos using Windows".

Now, insert your USB drive (with pictures only on it), and you will see the following:

[image]

Click "Import settings", and you will see:

[image]

Change the settings as you see fit, and click OK.